# HTTP Response Code 301 While Sending data from Arduino to Local Server

Tags: networking, arduino, arduino-c++

I am new to Arduino and Networking in general, and was trying to connect my ESP32 CAM to my local WiFi network and send a file from a SD Card in the ESP32 to a folder in my PC (which acts as a local server). Everything is working as expected, except the sending part.

The ESP32 CAM connects with the WiFi network and is able to read from the SD card without any issues. However, it is unable to send the data across to the local machine.

I am using XAMPP stack on my PC.

This is the configuration details for to connect to the network:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include "SD_MMC.h"

const char* ssid = "name";
const char* password = "pass";
const char* server = "192.168.0.106";
const int port = 8080;
const String path = "/ProjectFolder";
const char* filename = "/data.txt";//Name of Text File
```

This is the Post Request (After Reading from the SD card)

```
 http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  int httpCode = http.POST(data);
  http.addHeader("Location", "192.168.0.106:8080/ProjectFolder/");
   String response = http.getString();
  http.end();

  // Check HTTP response
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    Serial.printf("HTTP response code: %d\n", httpCode);
    Serial.println("HTTP response body: " + response);
  } else {
    Serial.println("HTTP request failed");
  }
```

However, the error that I am getting is:

```
HTTP response code: 301
HTTP response body: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://192.168.0.106:8080/ProjectFolder/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.2.0 Server at 192.168.0.106 Port 8080</address>
</body></html>
```

Things that I have tried:

- I have tried to access the same url from my phone using this `192.162.0.106:8080/ProjectFolder`. This works perfectly.
- I have also tried to replace the path with `/ProjectFolder/`

The directory is stored on my PC and does not contain any files.

In case you need more clarity, here is the complete code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include "SD_MMC.h"

const char* ssid = "name";
const char* password = "pass";
const char* server = "192.168.0.106";
const int port = 8080;
const String path = "/ProjectFolder";
const char* filename = "/data.txt"; // replace with your text file name on SD card


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi network
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi...");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  // Initialize SD card
  if (!SD_MMC.begin()) {
    Serial.println("SD card initialization failed");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("SD card initialized");
}

void loop() {
  // Wait for a few seconds
  delay(5000);
  
  // Check if connected to WiFi
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("WiFi connection lost");
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(1000);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("Reconnected to WiFi");
  }
  
  // Make HTTP request to server
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin("http://" + String(server) + ":" + String(port) + path);
  
  // Open the text file from SD card
  File file = SD_MMC.open(filename);
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file");
    return;
  }

  // Read the text file into a String object
  String data = "";
  while (file.available()) {
    data += char(file.read());
  }
  file.close();

  // Send the text file contents to the server
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  int httpCode = http.POST(data);
  http.addHeader("Location", "192.168.0.106:8080/ProjectFolder/");
   String response = http.getString();
  http.end();
  
  // Check HTTP response
  if (httpCode > 0) {
    Serial.printf("HTTP response code: %d\n", httpCode);
    Serial.println("HTTP response body: " + response);
  } else {
    Serial.println("HTTP request failed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use an old version of the esp8266 Arduino platform. In current versions (3+) the `begin` method of the ESP9266HTTPClient requires as first parameter an instance of the WiFiClient or WiFiClientSecure class.

Your server requires a secure connection (a.k.a. SSL). An instance of WiFiClientSecure provided to `http.begin` will handle the secure connection.

See the BasicHttpsClient example of the current version of the ESP8266HTTPClient library on how to initialize and use the WiFiClientSecure object.

Here is a simplified snippet without setting the SSL fingerprint:

```
WiFiClientSecure client;
client.setInsecure();
HTTPClient http;
http.begin(client, "http://" + String(server) + ":" + String(port) + path);
```

Comment: Hello @Juraj, I tried what you told me to do. However, now I am getting the error "HTTP request Failed". Sorry for the late reply.